# Provide Activity instance with Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

How can I translate something like this:

```
@Module
abstract class BaseActivityModule<A : AppCompatActivity> {
    @Binds
    abstract fun provideActivity(activity: A): AppCompatActivity

    companion object {
        @Provides
        @ActivityContext
        fun provideContext(activity: AppCompatActivity): Context = activity
    }
}

@Module
abstract class SomeActivityModule : BaseActivityModule<SomeActivity>()
```

So it can be used latter like:

```
@ActivityScope
class UtilsClass @Inject constructor(
    private val activity: AppCompatActivity,
    ...
){...}
```

I've migrated a playground project from `dagger` to `hilt` and it went super smooth, but I've stumbled across this use-case. I've changed the code so I wont be needing that instance any more but the curiosity remains.

Is it even possible now that we don't need this kind of setup:

```
@ActivityScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SomeActivityModule::class])
abstract fun someActivity(): SomeActivity
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i didn't try this code yet, if its not working please CMiMW,
according to documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#predefined-qualifiers), you can use predefined qualifers for Application Context and activity context.

your code may look like this

```
@ActivityScoped
class UtilsClass @Inject constructor(
@ActivityContext private val activity: Context,
... 
){
 ...
 val myActivity = if(context is MyActivity) context as MyActivity else throw ......  // check if its provided context was desired activity
 ...

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can cast `@ActivityContext` to that of your activity, read on for more clarification.
`@ActivityContext` can be used to scope the bindings that require activity context.
But similar to dagger scoping scheme, you can only scope in classes that are `@ActivityScoped`, i.e if you try `@ActivityContext` in a class and scope it with any other scope wider than `@ActivityScoped`, you will face compile time error

> @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ActivityContext
> android.content.Context cannot be provided without an
> @Provides-annotated method

Moreover, new bindings objects will instantiated every time any new activity is created.

refer https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-scopes

Answer (score 5):

Just cast/get activity from context. But you can also specify class according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-default)

```
tailrec fun Context?.activity(): Activity? = this as? Activity
    ?: (this as? ContextWrapper)?.baseContext?.activity()

class MyClass @Inject constructor(@ActivityContext context: Context) {

    init {
        val activity = context.activity() as Activity
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing situation while working on project, thought I would share if this helps someone.

The activity `Context` binding is available using `@ActivityContext`

```
class PaymentService @Inject constructor(
    @ActivityContext context: Context
) { ... }
```

and `Activity` binding is available without qualifiers.

```
class PaymentService @Inject constructor(
    activity: FragmentActivity
) { ... }
```

Comment: Hi Hussain, activity: ComponentActivity\contructor(activity: ComponentActivity) not work but activity: FragmentActivity\contructor(activity: FragmentActivity) like your answer above works well, I dont know why,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We don't need this kind of setup. We just have to provide @AndroidEntryPoint on our activities and Hilt will handle the dependency injections on its own. Also with Hilt, There is no need to write Factory and InjectorComponents.

Comment: Hello RatneZ, yup I know and that's pretty cool, but I was wondering if with Hilt it's possible to provide an Activity instance, and if so, how? I don't have a use-case for it, just curiosity, because with Dagger you can and Hilt uses Dagger under the hood.

Comment: Hey Guilhe, you can refer this answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/62538522/5815842